# Password Reset Through sms in django

Tags: django, django-forms, sms, django-views, twilio

Hey guys I am developing an app in Django in which i have customuser where every user have mobile number now what i need is to reset a password through mobile sms verification?

I didn't try anything yet because i don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need to communicate with a separate server which can send sms. Like this via rest http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/sms/sending-via-rest